# How to add a check constraint to confirm that a student can choose maximum five courses using SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

Is it possible to add a check constraint without using pl sql...I want to add it by SQL query only

Comment: As far as I can tell, that would be a database trigger, which means PL/SQL, which means **not** SQL.

Comment: that mean it is not possible by sql query! right?

Comment: @ShamimMohammad, Please be more elaborative, five courses are defined or is it static?

Comment: @Jåcob not defined..it is static..any of these he can choose but max 5

Answer (score 2):

One option to do this is by using materialized view with constraint. If you have table like this that stores association between a student and a course:

```
CREATE TABLE student_course (student_id NUMBER, course_id NUMBER);
```

Then define materialized view like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON student_course WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
(student_id, course_id)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW student_courses_count
PARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE  
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT AS  
SELECT student_id,
   COUNT(course_id) AS courses_count,
FROM student_course
GROUP BY student_id;

ALTER TABLE student_courses_count
  ADD CONSTRAINT student_courses_count_max CHECK( courses_count <= 5 );
```

So you first create materialized view that is updated on every change in the main table. And constraint is checked on the materialized view which is a derived table.

Lets assume you have some records in `student_course`:

```
student_id | course_id
-----------+-----------
        1  |        1
        1  |        2
        1  |        3
        2  |        2
        2  |        4
```

Materialized view would contain a result of the query that was used for materialized view definition. So for every `student_id` it would contain the number of records in `student_course`:

```
student_id | courses_count
-----------+--------------
        1  |          3
        2  |          2
```

In all respects materialized view behaves like a table but its content is created by running a query (in our case the query calculates the number of courses for each student). Given that materialized view is very much like a table we can add a constraint for a column that contains a number of courses that are associated with a student.

If you ever create a sixth course for some student the value in the `courses_count` column for that student would become 6 and this will cause constraint violation in the database. So such transaction will be rolled back and you would not be able to add more than 5 associations for the given student.

Comment: i am not understanding this method bro

Comment: I've added some explanation how this works. @ShamimMohammad if you can be more specific in what is not clear in my answer that would help me to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think its has multiple approach , 
one of them to has a column record number of course selected and give count , when add course give 1 , and another give 2 and so on , and put constraint check the value <= 5

Comment: how it possible..can you explain it? oracle said count function that is group functions are not allowed at check constraint

Comment: can you add a column to this table , for example named packageCNT

Comment: you set a value in column each time user add course , sure the count per user , then  put constraint on this column say its value can not be more than 5 .